# Hotel room Status generation in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having a table structure like this

```
id             int
checkinttime   datetime
checkouttime   datetime
roomid         int
```

I have recorded checkin and checkout time in this table. My question is how to generate a datewise report that generate whether room occupied or not in that date range like this.

```
room  3/1/2016 3/2/2016 3/3/2016 6/4/2016
r1      P         V       V        P
r2      v          p      p        p
```

where p means Occupied, and V means vacant. How to write SQL for this.?

Thanks in advance.

[image: This is the structure. customer select start date and end date. With that parameters, room and date wise details are needed.]

Comment: you have another table for rooms, haven't you ?

Comment: yes, there is a room table. roomid is foreign key..

Comment: I think instead of making the date range as dynamic, use room id as columns and date tange as rows.

Comment: you can refer to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157282/generate-days-from-date-range?lq=1

Comment: I'd suggest to 1) populate persistent table `calendar` 2) link `calendar` filtered by period range with `rooms` via cross join 3) `left join` checkin-checkout table 4) build pivoted table (with separate column per date) on client-side/frontend

Answer (score 2):

A solution is to use a static query over rooms as columns like this:

```
;WITH dates(date) AS (
    SELECT @startDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, date)
    FROM dates
    WHERE date < @endDate
), occupied AS (
SELECT date, c.booking_id
FROM dates d
    LEFT JOIN  -- You can use `JOIN` only also to remove free dates
    CheckStatus c ON d.date BETWEEN c.checkin_time AND c.checkout_time
)
SELECT date
    , MIN(CASE WHEN id = 1 THEN 'P' ELSE 'V' END) AS 'r1'
    , MIN(CASE WHEN id = 2 THEN 'P' ELSE 'V' END) AS 'r2'
FROM occupied
GROUP BY date;
```

The result will be like this:

```
date       | r1 | r2 |
-----------+----+----+
2016-03-01 | P  | V  |
2016-03-02 | V  | P  |
2016-03-03 | V  | P  |
2016-03-04 | V  | P  |
```

Comment: please write complete query with parameters startdate and enddate

Comment: with those parameters it can be easier ;).

Comment: thanks Sha for your support. I uploaded image. Please check it.

Comment: what is daterange means here.?

Comment: Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'dateRange'.

Comment: Msg 240, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "date" of recursive query "dates".

Comment: What is type of `@startDate`? it should be `datetime` => Also `@endDate` ;).

Comment: startDate and endDate are datetime parameters.  is it will result all rooms?

Comment: this query is to generate report that shows all rooms status between a start date and end date.

Comment: this is static for two rooms you need to add `, MIN(CASE WHEN id = i THEN 'P' ELSE 'V' END) AS 'ri'` for each room

Comment: is it possible for automatically select all rooms from table as I uploaded image in question. if possible please update query. I connected checkstatus table bookingid with bookingtable and roomname.

Comment: Then you need to use Dynamic SQL ;).

Comment: its work, but how i can show The userName in the user table.
(reservation table has userId).
thanks in advance